# Displaying posts by year

Tags: categories, query-posts, query, date, variables

I'm trying to display posts on the homepage from the current year only. I am using the following:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page()) { ?>
    <?php $current_year = date('Y');  ?>
    <?php query_posts( "&year=$current_year&order=DESC"); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Yet it doesn't seem to work. I also tried:

```
<?php query_posts( "&year=' + $current_year + '&order=DESC"); ?>
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in what way? If `is_front_page` returning true? Also, you should seriously consider using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of query_posts.

Comment: `+` is not a concatenation operator in PHP so your second attempt wouldn't work, plus you've actually passed the `+` in the string and I don't think you meant to. You have a string literally like `"&year=' + 2013 + '&order=DESC"`. It should be `'&year='.$current_year.'&order=DESC'` but that is equivalent to the code in double quotes.